# Playframework 2.3 wrong apache proxy configuration on centos 7

Tags: apache, playframework, proxy, playframework-2.3, centos7

Hello I have vps with installed centos 7 on the board and apache server which I am trying to use a proxy server to my two different playframework2.3 applications

> I have started those applications with following comands 
>   App1: start -Dhttp.port=8000 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 
>   App2: start -Dhttp.port=8001 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.2

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    ProxyPass /excluded !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    ProxyPass /excluded !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.2:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.2:8001/
</VirtualHost>
```

As long as I had only one domain it have worked as I expected. By pointing to domain1.com in the browser I could see App1 content. Since I added second app, the second app configuration overrides firstly configured App1. So by pointing to doamin2.com it works, I can see the second application App2, but when I go to domain1.com I can see the App2 content as well

At the end my both domains points to the same application App2

What am I doing wrong ?
Why firstly configured App1 is overriden by App2 configuration ?
Should I add those domains to the hosts file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing preceding www from each ServerNames